# Redirecting all outgoing HTTP traffic from one computer to another on a DD-WRT router

Tags: networking, iptables

I am trying to debug some HTTP traffic from one computer (let's call it A) on my network. I would like to redirect all of that traffic to another computer (let's call it B) without changing any configuration on A directly. B is running a webserver which logs all HTTP requests that are made to it. Both of these computers are connected to the network using a router running DD-WRT.

I believe that it should be possible to do this redirection using iptables. I have come up with the following iptables configuration:

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB:80`

When I load this in the router, A stops getting any response at all from HTTP requests sent out, but B doesn't see anything at all.

How can I make this work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Usually, you redirect outgoing HTTP traffic to a proxy (not a web server) for caching and filtering.

Comment: I ultimately want to have a proxy server set up so that I have A -> B -> outside server, but I cannot modify device A. As a first test, I just wanted to see that I would actually have the requests forwarded to B (which would be my proxy server), but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Try it with a proxy server that supports transparent proxy such as squid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becouse you have computer B on same network with A, the B send reply directly to A and not through router, so DNAT not work.

You have to add additional iptables command to change source of IP from A, so the B will send packet to router, DNAT make backwards translation and send reply to A.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA -d BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source IP.OF.GW.LAN
```

Where IP.OF.GW.LAN is IP address of your router on LAN interface, but theoretically you can set any address which is not in your local network. All request on BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB from AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA you will see coming from IP.OF.GW.LAN